# Does 2010's SQL Reporting Services still use the 2005 Service for Report Service Execution?

Tags: sql, reporting-services

In 2005, SQL Reporting Services had two separate services:

```
 http://[server]/reportserver/reportexecution2005.asmx
```

and

```
 http://[server[/reportserver/reportservice2005.asmx
```

In 2010, the reportservice2005.asmx has been replaces with reportservice2010.asmx.  There are some differences between the two, but so far I've been able to navigate them ok.

But what I am not finding is any new service for reportexecution2005.asmx.  And it does not appear that the functionality in this service has been rolled into reportservice2010.asmx.

So, for actually rendering reports, should I still just use reportservice2005.asmx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Report Server Web Service Endpoints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155398.aspx) and more specific the **Execution Endpoints** section I would say that [ReportExecution2005 Namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportexecution2005.aspx) is still the way to go.

> The ReportExecution2005 endpoint makes it easy for developers to
>   customize report processing and rendering from a report server in both
>   native and SharePoint integrated modes. The endpoint includes classes
>   and methods that existed in earlier versions of the Report Server Web
>   service. In addition, many new classes and methods have been added to
>   the Report Server Web service that are exposed through the execution
>   endpoint.

Comment: Thanks.  I was starting to expect as much, but wanted some external conformation.